# How can I get the entire covariance matrix from coeftest() of a panel model

Tags: covariance, plm

I'm running panel regressions using the `plm` package like this:

```
library("plm")
Data <- data.frame(id = c(rep("a",50), rep("b", 50)),
               y = rnorm(100),
               x = c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50, sd = 5)),
               z = c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50, sd = 3)))

panelmodel <- plm(y ~ x + z, 
                  data = Data, 
                  effect = "individual", 
                  model = "within", 
                  index = "id")
```

I want to adjust my standard errors for clustering which I can do using the `lmtest` package like:

```
library("lmtest")
coeftest(panelmodel, 
     vcov = vcovHC(panelmodel, 
                   type = "sss"), # I need this exact type of standard errors
     cluster = "id")
```

But I need the cluster adjusted covariance matrix that was used to calculate the standard errors here. The non-adjusted covariance matrix is used above and it is this:

```
vcovHC(panelmodel, type = "sss")
```

But this is not yet adjusted. How can I get the covariance matrix that coeftest has calculated to return the adjusted standard errors? I need that for further calculations with different covariances.

The `multiwayvcov` package unfortunately does not work with plm objects so that one is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation: `?plm::vcovHC.plm`: `vcovHC(panelmodel, type = "sss")` is already what you are looking for, it is the same as `vcovHC(panelmodel, type = "sss", cluster = "group")`.

The argument `cluster` you are passing to `coeftest()` (and not to `vcovHC()`) is not evaluated as it is an unknown argument of the function and the function it is passed to (for your example, at least). You can check by comparing the results of these three commands, they are all the same:

```
coeftest(panelmodel, vcov. = vcovHC(panelmodel, type = "sss"))
coeftest(panelmodel, vcov. = vcovHC(panelmodel, type = "sss"), cluster = "id")
coeftest(panelmodel, vcov. = vcovHC(panelmodel, type = "sss"), cluster = "nonsense")
```

Comment: Thanks and you are correct. Strange then that so many how-tos include this as a way to cluster like this one: https://blog.theleapjournal.org/2016/06/sophisticated-clustered-standard-errors.html

Comment: Well, in the blog, the argument `cluster` is placed as an argument for `vcovHC` (from package plm) - this works. In the code in your question you placed it as an argument to `coeftest`.